# Syntax Highlighter putting new lines randomly (or maybe after every symbol)

Tags: php, codeigniter, syntax-highlighting

I am using a simple implementation of Syntax Highlighter for a blog written in CodeIgniter. Here is the link http://code.angad.sg/index.php/blog/test

Not sure why is this happening. I am not pasting the source code for the file; you can do a Ctrl+U on the link.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem lies in your CSS in code.css:

```
code {
 font-family: Monaco, Verdana, Sans-serif;
 font-size: 12px;
 background-color: #f9f9f9;
 border: 1px solid #D0D0D0;
 color: #002166;
 display: block;
 margin: 14px 0 14px 0;
 padding: 12px 10px 12px 10px;
}
```

In particular, the `display: block;` messes things up, since every token is wrapped inside of its own `<code>` tag.